# Align Title or Caption with Image?

Tags: xml, image, apache-fop, docbook

I'm working with DockBook 4.5 and Apache FOP 1.1 on Ubuntu 13.04. The Docbook translation are provided by Ubuntu and FOP was downloaded directly from Apache.

First question: would someone please tell me how to ensure the title or caption of a image is aligned with the image? For example:

```
 Figure X: YYYYYY
 +---------------+
 |               |
 |     Image     |
 |               |
 +---------------+
```

I know I can align the `imagedata` with the following:

```
<figure id="figure-xxx">
<title>YYYYY</title>

  <mediaobject>
    <imageobject>
      <imagedata align="center" fileref="xxx.png" scale="75"/>
    </imageobject>
    <caption>XXX/caption>
  </mediaobject>
</figure>
```

However, `align="center"` produces something like:

```
 Figure X: YYYYYY
           +---------------+
           |               |
           |     Image     |
           |               |
           +---------------+
```

And `align="right"` makes it worse:

```
 Figure X: YYYYYY
                     +---------------+
                     |               |
                     |     Image     |
                     |               |
                     +---------------+
```

When I attempt to add the `align` tag to the `figure`, `title`, `mediaobject`, `imageobject`, or `caption`, I get an errors similar to:

```
element figure: validity error : No declaration for attribute align of element figure
```

and:

```
element mediaobject: validity error : No declaration for attribute align of element mediaobject
```

Perhaps I'm doing something wrong again. After trying to flow text around an image ([Block Image Right and Flow Text Around It?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19771669/block-image-right-and-flow-text-around-it)) and align the caption to the image (this question), I'm left wondering if DocBook can work with images in real life.

So my second question: does anyone know if DocBook supports images in real life?

EDIT: for the answer to the second question, the problem is with Apache FOP and not DocBook.

Comment: Could you try setting the width on the `<figure>` tag? I am unfamiliar with DocBook, but I am sure basic styling rules apply: http://jsfiddle.net/MrPolywhirl/GTckP/?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume that "Docbook translation" means [docbook-xsl](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=docbook-xsl) (I don't think the exact version matters much here, but often it can be important).

You can work around the title alignment problem by customizing the `formal.title.properties` attribute-set. Add this to your customization layer:

```
<xsl:attribute-set name="formal.title.properties">
 <xsl:attribute name="text-align">
  <xsl:variable name ="align">
    <xsl:value-of select=".//imagedata/@align"/>
  </xsl:variable>
  <xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="self::figure and $align !=''">
     <xsl:value-of select="$align"/>
    </xsl:when>
   <xsl:otherwise>left</xsl:otherwise>
  </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:attribute-set>
```

Meaning: if there is an `align` value on the  `imagedata` element, use that value for the figure title, otherwise use "left".

See also http://www.sagehill.net/docbookxsl/TitleFontSizes.html#FormalTitleProperties.

Comment: Thanks mzjn. I already stopped using Apache's FOP. It has too many problems (like this and silently dropping floating images/figures).